# bash/zsh input process substitution gives syntax error in conjunction with while

Tags: bash, zsh

These work fine and do what they should (print the contents of the file foo):

```
cat <foo
while read line; do echo $line; done <foo
cat <(cat foo)
```

However this gives me a syntax error in zsh:

```
zsh$ while read line; do echo $line; done <(cat foo)
zsh: parse error near `<(cat foo)'
```

and bash:

```
bash$ while read line; do echo $line; done <(cat foo)
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `<(cat foo)'
```

Does anybody know the reason and maybe a workaround?

Note: This is obviously a toy example. In the real code I need the body of the while loop to be executed in the main shell process, so I can't just use

```
cat foo | while read line; do echo $line; done
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to redirect the process substitution into the while loop:

You wrote

```
while read line; do echo $line; done <(cat foo)
```

You need

```
while read line; do echo $line; done < <(cat foo)
# ...................................^
```

Treat a process substitution like a filename.

Comment: Yes, exactly. I figured it out a minute before your post and answered myself :) But I'll instead delete my answer and accept yours. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

**`bash`/`zsh` replaces `<(cat foo)` by a pipe (kind of file) having a name as `/dev/fd/n` where `n` is the file descriptor (number).**

You can check the pipe name using the command `echo <(cat foo)`.

As you may know, `bash`/`zsh` also runs the command `cat foo` in another process. The output of this second process is written to that named pipe.

**without process substitution:**

```
while ... do ... done   inputfile #error
while ... do ... done < inputfile #correct
```

**same rules using process substitution:**

```
while ... do ... done   <(cat foo) #error
while ... do ... done < <(cat foo) #correct
```

**Alternative:**

```
cat foo >3 & while read line; do echo $line; done <3;
```

Comment: Interesting! Do you have a source for this or do you know the reason why while does not support this? I did not find this in the manpage. Your workaround would run the while loop in a subshell which causes problems in my real script. Any idea how it could be changed so that the while loop runs in the main shell?

Answer (score 2):

I can suggest only workaround like this:

```
theproc() { for((i=0;i<5;++i)) do echo $i; }

while read line ; do echo $line ; done <<<"$(theproc)"
```

Comment: No, sorry, that's not it at all. I'm not even sure what "eval $(cat)" is supposed to do. It will just block and wait for input.

Comment: Oh, and <(foo) is process substitution. It will create temporary named pipe, execute the process foo with its stdout redirected into the named pipe and then execute the stuff before the <( ) with its stdin redirected to the named pipe. See the man pages of bash and zsh for details.

Comment: Yes, I definitely misunderstood you, but since that I've updated the answer :)

Comment: Yes, this is the line I mentioned at the beginning. I know that this works. But in my real script I'm actually executing a process and not simply reading a file. So this is not an option.
I also know that I could just save it into a temp file and that's what I'm doing right now as a workaround. I'm just curious why the process substitution does not work in this case...

Comment: Oops, got it. Well, what is your bash version and platform? That works for me, bash manpage says it's supported on platoforms supporting named pipes or the /dev/fd, which is probably more or less everything.

Comment: Interesting approach. It almost works, too. The only problem is that it will mess up the line breaks unless you also set IFS to "" before. So, yes it's a workaround, but at this point, the temp file feels like the cleaner solution :)

Comment: I'm also really surprised that "while ... <<<" works, and "while ... <( )" does not...

Comment: Well, the IFS issue is independent of piping mechanisms. The difference is probably somehow related to the platform and/or bash version. (and no, I don't think temp file is generally a cleaner solution, I hate temporary files:))

Comment: No it's not. IFS has no effect on `<file` or `< <(command)` (the correct solution).

Comment: Just try `while read line; do echo $line; done < <(echo "line1"; echo "line2")` and `while read line; do echo $line; done <<<$(echo "line1"; echo "line2")` and check out the difference...

Comment: But you missed the quotes. In my example, they are there. Try `while read line; do echo $line; done <<<"$(echo "line1"; echo "line2")"` instead.